# MIPS read integer from array

Tags: arrays, assembly, integer, mips

I'm trying to write Barcode 128 decoder using MIPS. I want to store patterns of every character as integers combined into an array. It looks like this:

```
.data       #file data.asm
code_0:     .word   0x6CC
code_1:     .word   0x66C
code_2:     .word   0x666
code_3:     .word   0x498
code_4:     .word   0x48C
code_5:     .word   0x44C
code_6:     .word   0x4C8
code_7:     .word   0x4C4
code_8:     .word   0x464
code_9:     .word   0x648
code_10:    .word   0x644
code_11:    .word   0x624
code_12:    .word   0x59C
code_13:    .word   0x4DC
code_14:    .word   0x4CE
code_15:    .word   0x5CC
code_16:    .word   0x4EC
code_17:    .word   0x4E6
code_18:    .word   0x672
code_19:    .word   0x65C
code_20:    .word   0x64E
code_21:    .word   0x6E4
code_22:    .word   0x674
code_23:    .word   0x76E
code_24:    .word   0x74C
code_25:    .word   0x72C
code_26:    .word   0x726
code_27:    .word   0x764
code_28:    .word   0x734
code_29:    .word   0x732
code_30:    .word   0x6D8
code_31:    .word   0x6C6
code_32:    .word   0x636
code_33:    .word   0x518
code_34:    .word   0x458
code_35:    .word   0x446
code_36:    .word   0x588
code_37:    .word   0x468
code_38:    .word   0x462
code_39:    .word   0x688
code_40:    .word   0x628
code_41:    .word   0x622
code_42:    .word   0x5B8
code_43:    .word   0x58E
code_44:    .word   0x46E
code_45:    .word   0x5D8
code_46:    .word   0x5C6
code_47:    .word   0x476
code_48:    .word   0x776
code_49:    .word   0x68E
code_50:    .word   0x62E
code_51:    .word   0x6E8
code_52:    .word   0x6E2
code_53:    .word   0x6EE
code_54:    .word   0x758
code_55:    .word   0x746
code_56:    .word   0x716
code_57:    .word   0x768
code_58:    .word   0x762
code_59:    .word   0x71A
code_60:    .word   0x77A
code_61:    .word   0x642
code_62:    .word   0x78A
code_63:    .word   0x530
code_64:    .word   0x50C
code_65:    .word   0x4B0
code_66:    .word   0x486
code_67:    .word   0x42C
code_68:    .word   0x426
code_69:    .word   0x590
code_70:    .word   0x584
code_71:    .word   0x4D0
code_72:    .word   0x4C2
code_73:    .word   0x434
code_74:    .word   0x432
code_75:    .word   0x612
code_76:    .word   0x650
code_77:    .word   0x7BA
code_78:    .word   0x614
code_79:    .word   0x47A
code_80:    .word   0x53C
code_81:    .word   0x4BC
code_82:    .word   0x49E
code_83:    .word   0x5E4
code_84:    .word   0x4F4
code_85:    .word   0x4F2
code_86:    .word   0x7A4
code_87:    .word   0x794
code_88:    .word   0x792
code_89:    .word   0x6DE
code_90:    .word   0x6F6
code_91:    .word   0x7B6
code_92:    .word   0x578
code_93:    .word   0x51E
code_94:    .word   0x45E
code_95:    .word   0x5E8
code_96:    .word   0x5E2
code_97:    .word   0x7A8
code_98:    .word   0x7A2
code_99:    .word   0x5DE
code_100:   .word   0x5EE
code_101:   .word   0x75E
code_102:   .word   0x7AE
code_103:   .word   0x684
code_104:   .word   0x690
code_105:   .word   0x69C
code_106:   .word   0x18EB

array_of_codes:
        .word   code_0, code_1, code_2, code_3, code_4, code_5, code_6, code_7, code_8, code_9, code_10,
                code_11, code_12, code_13, code_14, code_15, code_16, code_17, code_18, code_19, code_20,
                code_21, code_22, code_23, code_24, code_25, code_26, code_27, code_28, code_29, code_30
                code_31, code_32, code_33, code_34, code_35, code_36, code_37, code_38, code_39, code_40,
                code_41, code_42, code_43, code_44, code_45, code_46, code_47, code_48, code_49, code_50,
                code_51, code_52, code_53, code_54, code_55, code_56, code_57, code_58, code_59, code_60
                code_61, code_62, code_63, code_64, code_65, code_66, code_67, code_68, code_69, code_70,
                code_71, code_72, code_73, code_74, code_75, code_76, code_77, code_78, code_79, code_80,
                code_81, code_82, code_83, code_84, code_85, code_86, code_87, code_88, code_89, code_90,
                code_91, code_92, code_93, code_94, code_95, code_96, code_97, code_98, code_99, code_100,
                code_101, code_102, code_103, code_104, code_105, code_106
```

It is very convenient way to do so, because in barcode 128, every character is encoded as a sequence of widths of consecutive black bars and white spaces (f.e. if we consider '!' symbol, which is 11001101100 or 222122 depending on the notation, it means that we have black bar of width 2, white space of width 2, black bar of width 2, white space of width 1 etc.). My problem is to read values from array holding all the codes. The code bellow should do the job:

```
la  $t5, array_of_codes
lw  $t4, ($t5) # now t4 should store the code_0 value, which is 0x6CC
```

but the value stored by t4 register isn't equal to 0x6CC (code_0 value). The strange thing is that every time i increment address on t5 by 4 (to get next integer in array), value read to t4 is also incremented by 4 bytes with refer to the old one (as you can see the values vary a lot and there is no 4-byte-difference pattern between every two values). I think that I've made a crucial mistake somewhere, probably operating on wrong addresses instead of words. If you need some reference to how my whole code looks like, I post it below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
.data
.include        "data.asm"

buffer:         .space  2
header:         .space  54
width:          .word   600
height:         .word   50
code_buffer:        .space  7
special_code_buffer:    .space  8
output:         .space  100

dsc_error_msg:      .asciiz "File descriptor error!"
bitmap_error_msg:   .asciiz "Loaded file is not a bitmap!"
format_error_msg:   .asciiz "Loaded bmp resolution is not 24-bit!"
size_error_msg:     .asciiz "Wrong file size! Allowed size is 600x50."
checksum_error_msg: .asciiz "Wrong checksum value!"
char_code_error_msg:    .asciiz "Character code not found!"
no_barcode_error_msg:   .asciiz "There is no barcode in the picture!"

no_black_pixel:     .asciiz "There is no barcode in the bitmap!"
placeholder:        .asciiz "Black pixel found!"

fpath:          .asciiz "/home/mateusz/develop/projects/ecoar/mips/Code-128-Decoder/abcd.bmp"

.text
open_file:

    li  $v0, 13
    la  $a0, fpath
    li  $a1, 0
    li  $a2, 0
    syscall

    bltz    $v0, dsc_file_error
    move    $s0, $v0

    li  $v0, 14
    move    $a0, $s0
    la  $a1, header
    li  $a2, 54
    syscall

    li  $t0, 0x4D42
    lhu $t1, header

    bne $t0, $t1, bitmap_error

    lw  $t0, width
    lw  $s1, header+18
    bne $t0, $s1, size_error
    lw  $t0, height
    lw  $s2, header+22
    bne $t0, $s2, size_error

    li  $t0, 24
    lb  $t1, header+28
    bne $t0, $t1, format_error

    lw  $s3, header+34

    li  $v0, 9
    move    $a0, $s3
    syscall
    move    $s4, $v0

    li  $v0, 14
    move    $a0, $s0
    move    $a1, $s4
    move    $a2, $s3
    syscall

close_file:
    li  $v0, 16
    move    $a0, $s0
    syscall

set_up:
    move    $t9, $s4
    li  $s4, 0
    li  $t7, 30 #line_number
    li  $t6, 1800
    mul $t7, $t7, $t6
    addu    $t9, $t9, $t7
    li  $t8, 0 # chcecking if we passed full row
    la  $a3, output
    xor $s4, $s4, $s4
    xor $s7, $s7, $s7
    xor $s6, $s6, $s6
    xor $s5, $s5, $s5

look_for_black:
    lb  $t0, ($t9)
    beqz    $t0, black_found

iterate:
    addiu   $t9, $t9, 3
    addiu   $t8, $t8, 1
    beq $t8, 599, no_barcode
    j   look_for_black

black_found:
    li  $t1, 1
    la  $t7, ($t9)

find_width:
    addiu   $t7, $t7, 3
    lb  $t0, ($t7)
    bnez    $t0, end_of_bar
    addiu   $t1, $t1, 1
    j   find_width

end_of_bar:
    divu    $t6, $t1, 2
    move    $t7, $t6 # width of the thinest bar in pixels
    mulu    $t6, $t7, 5 # firt width which exceeds limit of 5

pre_prepare:
    xor $s0, $s0, $s0 # pattern
    xor $s1, $s1, $s1 # number of shifts
    li  $s2, 1
    li  $s3, 0

prepare:
    li  $t1, 0
    lb  $t2, ($t9) # current color

get_bar:
    lb  $t0, ($t9)
    addiu   $t1, $t1, 1
    addiu   $t9, $t9, 3
    move    $t3, $t2 # hold color
    beq $t1, $t7, bar_obtained
    j   get_bar

bar_obtained:
    beq $t2, 0xffffff, white_bar
    beq $t2, 0x000000, black_bar

white_bar:
    or  $s0, $s0, $s3
    sll $s0, $s0, 1
    addiu   $s1, $s1, 1
    beq $s1, 10, pattern_finished
    j   prepare

black_bar:
    or  $s0, $s0, $s2
    sll $s0, $s0, 1
    addiu   $s1, $s1, 1
    beq $s1, 10, pattern_finished
    j   prepare

pattern_finished:
    li  $t1, 0
    la  $t5, array_of_codes


compare:
    lw  $t4, ($t5)
    beq $s0, $t4, equal
    bne $s0, $t4, not_equal

equal:
    beq $t1, 103, start
    addiu   $s4, $s4, 1
    move    $s5, $t1
    mulu    $s6, $s4, $s5
    addu    $s7, $s7, $s6
    addiu   $t1, $t1, 32
    sb  $t1, ($a3)
    addiu   $a3, $a3, 1
    xor $s0, $s0, $s0
    xor $s1, $s1, $s1
    j   prepare

start:
    addu    $s4, $s4, $t1
    j   prepare


not_equal:
    addiu   $t1, $t1, 1
    beq $t1, 105, possible_stop
    addiu   $t5, $t5, 4
    j   compare

possible_stop:
    xor $s0, $s0, $s0
    xor $s1, $s1, $s1

get_bars:
    li  $t1, 0
    lb  $t2, ($t9)

get_additional_bars:
    lb  $t0, ($t9)
    addiu   $t1, $t1, 1
    addiu   $t9, $t9, 3
    move    $t3, $t2 # hold color
    beq $t1, $t7, additional_obtained
    j   get_bar

additional_obtained:
    beq $t2, 0xffffff, white_bar_add
    beq $t2, 0x000000, black_bar_add

white_bar_add:
    or  $s0, $s0, $s3
    sll $s0, $s0, 1
    addiu   $s1, $s1, 1
    beq $s1, 2, finalize
    j   get_bars

black_bar_add:
    or  $s0, $s0, $s3
    sll $s0, $s0, 1
    addiu   $s1, $s1, 1
    beq $s1, 2, finalize
    j   get_bars

finalize:
    la  $a1, array_of_codes+424
    lw  $a2, ($a1)
    bne $s0, $a2, wrong_code
    beq $s0, $a2, match

match:
    subu    $s7, $s7, $s6
    li  $t4, 103
    divu    $s7, $t4
    xor $t4, $t4, $t4
    mfhi    $t4
    bne $t4, $s5 wrong_checksum

finish:
    li  $t3, '\0'
    subiu   $a3, $a3, 1
    sb  $t3, ($a3)

exit_success:
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, output
    syscall
    li  $v0, 10
    syscall


no_barcode:
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, no_barcode_error_msg
    syscall
    j   exit

wrong_checksum:
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, checksum_error_msg
    syscall
    j   exit

wrong_code:
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, char_code_error_msg
    syscall
    j   exit

black_not_found:
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, no_black_pixel
    syscall
    j   exit


dsc_file_error:
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, dsc_error_msg
    syscall
    j   exit

bitmap_error:
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, bitmap_error_msg
    syscall
    j   exit

size_error:
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, size_error_msg
    syscall
    j   exit

format_error:
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, format_error_msg
    syscall
    j   exit

exit:
    li  $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: `lw  $t4, ($t5)`  now t4 stores the *address* of `code_0`, because you made an array of pointers!  You don't need the extra level of indirection: just put `array_of_codes:` label in front of the `code_0:` line, so `array[0]` has the same address as `code_0`.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you very much, that was the fix to my problem.